# Extracting only peaks in a distribution

Tags: opencv, gnuplot

I have a table that has frame numbers in one column and corresponding color moments in the other column. I found them using openCV. 
Some of the frames have extremely high values and rest very low. How can I extract the frames with very high peaks ?

This is the plot of the distribution, I tried to use Gaussian smoothing and then thresholding on the plot below.

[image: Plot]

I got this result.

[image: Plot1]

Now how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are looking for a peakfinder...MATLAB has a peakfinder function to find peaks...
I did not find any ready made API in OpenCV for this so I implemented the peakfinder of MATLAB...the algorithm goes this way...

1. Initial assumptions or prior knowledge can be **a)** you can have 'n' peaks in your distribution **b)** your peaks are separated by a minimum window 'w' i.e no two peak are closer than 'w'.
2. I can tel you the window implementation. Start at a data point . Mark its position as current index and check in its left and right neighbourhood of length 'w' whether a value more than the value at current index exists or not.
3. If yes move to the point. Make the point the current index and repeat 2.
4. If no then its your local maxima. Move ur current index by 'w' length and repeat 2 till you reach data set end.

try to implement this and check MATLAB help for peakfinder. If no luck I can post the code..

**EDIT** after seeing your edited graph it seems the graph has well defined maximum peaks and hence what you can do is track the sign of the dy/dx of the graph. Maximum peaks are points where sign of dy/dx changes from positive to negative...in code language

```
vector<double> array_of_max_peak;
if (sign( x(n+1) - x(n) ) ) > 0
  array_of_max_peak.push(x(n));
```

Comment: Pretty much all peak finders are a derivative of this algorithm in one form or another.

Comment: @rotating_image I tried some other methods of peak finding. First I did and smoothing and then thresholding. I got a graph that I have added in the question above.